# duplicated outputs of np.apply_along_axis when a dict is returned

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

Check this piece of code snippet,

```
import numpy as np    
a = np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)

# the result is right if there is only 1 key
func = lambda x: dict(k1=len(x))
print np.apply_along_axis(func, -1, a)
out[1]: [[{'k1': 10}]
         [{'k1': 10}]]

# but if there are more than 1 key in the returned dict
# the results are duplicated
func = lambda x: dict(k1=1, k2=len(x))
print np.apply_along_axis(func, -1, a)
out[2]: [[{'k2': 10, 'k1': 1} {'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}]
          [{'k2': 10, 'k1': 1} {'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}]]

func = lambda x: dict(k1=1, k2=2, k3=len(x))
print np.apply_along_axis(func, -1, a)
out[3]: [[{'k3': 10, 'k2': 2, 'k1': 1} {'k3': 10, 'k2': 2, 'k1': 1} {'k3': 10, 'k2': 2, 'k1': 1}]
         [{'k3': 10, 'k2': 2, 'k1': 1} {'k3': 10, 'k2': 2, 'k1': 1} {'k3': 10, 'k2': 2, 'k1': 1}]]
```

The problem has been described in the comments and the results have been shown also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `np.apply_along_axis` is trying to figure out what the resulting shape should be, based on the result of calling `func`.  If your input array has shape `(n, m)` and your `func` returns something with length `k`, then `np.apply_along_axis(func, -1, a)` will return an array of shape `(n, k)`.  This is true even if your function returns something other than a list or an array.  If your function returns a scalar, the resulting shape will be `(n,)`.

Examples:

```
# np.diff(a[0]) has length 9.
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.diff(x), -1, a).shape
(2, 9)
# sorted(a[0]) has length 10
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: sorted(x), -1, a).shape
(2, 10)
# len(a[0]) is a scalar
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: len(x), -1, a).shape
(2,)
```

Now, in your case, since you're returning a `dict` with length 2, the resulting shape is `(2, 2)`.  A simple workaround would be to wrap the dictionary in something that's a scalar.  But apparently, numpy doesn't like custom scalars.  So if you try to use a custom `DictWrap` class like this:

```
class DictWrap(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._d = dict(*args, **kwargs)
```

...it doesn't work:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: DictWrap(k1=1, k2=len(x)), -1, a)
...
TypeError: object of type 'DictWrap' has no len()
```

So either we need to add a custom `__len__()` method to `DictWrap` which returns 1, or we can wrap the dictionary in a list:

```
>>> np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [dict(k1=1, k2=len(x))], -1, a)
array([[{'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}],
       [{'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}]], dtype=object)
```

This has a shape `(2, 1)`.  You can call `squeeze()` on it to get a 1-d array:

```
>>> r = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: [dict(k1=1, k2=len(x))], -1, a)
>>> r.squeeze()
array([{'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}, {'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}], dtype=object)
```

Another, and perhaps the easiest, way would be to get rid of the extra dimensions yourself:

```
>>> r = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: dict(k1=1, k2=len(x)), -1, a)
>>> r[:, 0]
array([{'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}, {'k2': 10, 'k1': 1}], dtype=object)
```

To see how exactly numpy handles various cases, see [documentation of `apply_along_axis`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.11.0/numpy/lib/shape_base.py#L20-L131) (particularly starting at `if isscalar(res):`).

Comment: I have to say `numpy` makes smug things